# Error: Stripe.js token was not passed! Report this message to the site administrator" for Stripe extension

Tags: payment-processor, stripe

I have following configuration: CiviCRM version - 4.6.2 Stripe version: 1.9.1

I have configured stripe on site and using it on contribution page and trying to use with "PayPal payment processor" and "Pay-later option".

After submitting the contribution I have getting the error as follows:

"Error: Stripe.js token was not passed! Report this message to the site administrator"

Is above error getting due to compatibility issue? Because on https://civicrm.org/extensions/stripe-payment-processor/ in this page compatibility for stripe with CiviCRM version for 4.4 and 4.5 is mentioned

Please guide!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem also.
It's a known issue with version 1.9.1 [You can view the Github thread here.](https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/issues/76)
The developer says his latest commit may have  [fixed the issue.](https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/pull/105)

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the reply....  I  already checked the link you mentioned in your answer. But the patch is not working mentioned in  https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/pull/105.

I have done some debugging. While submitting the form the $params['stripe_token'] is getting empty.

Answer (score 0):

This should have been solved back in November 2015 (worked on CiviCRM 4.6.9).

I am trying to bring order to the issue reports scattered across here & GitHub and get appropriate issues closed.

(Note: It was not the PR on 105 that fixed, but a different commit afterwards).  Use the 4.6-dev branch from GitHub.